# How long is a 255-byte string in the context of HTTP requests?

Tags: string, http, url, encoding, ascii

I have a problem with long urls in the context of video streaming via the amazon cloudfront cdn and signedd urls on a media-box.

[RFC 2068 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2068.html#b) states:

```
 Note: Servers should be cautious about depending on URI lengths
 above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations
 may not properly support these lengths.
```

This seems to be exactly the limitation i am running into. Because 255 character long urls work, 256 characters don't.

However I am a little confused because I thought in ASCII a character is encoded by 7 bit.

I also know that the valid characters in an URL are entirely covered by the ascii alphabet.

I do know that it is common practice to extend to an 8-bit alphabet to support more characters or use the one bit missing to one byte for error detection/correction.

My question now is:

In the context of http requests. What exactly is meant when speaking of a length of 255 bytes. How many characters and how is this number reproduceable?

Comment: You should rely on [RFC 2161](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) about HTTP 1.1 in general (although it says the same thing in this particular case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ascii only *uses* the first 7 bits of each byte, but every character still takes up one byte.

Comment: +1 ... thats what i figured somehow... where can i reed up on that? and can you imagine a reason for that? ... isnt it wasted data?

Comment: The biggest reason is that the world just works with 8bit bytes. I bet ASCII stems from a time where perhaps where CPU's with 7-bit registers were around. Can't really do your research, but you have your answer :)

Comment: "where can i reed up on that?"
You may have to find a papyrus scroll to reed up on it.

Answer (score 3):

255 bytes would be 255 characters here. This note is a rule of thumb. Unless you're going via a proxy, most URIs will be split in the request header (the host is generally in the `Host` header, not on the request line).

I think this 255-byte limit is generally obsolete with current software, although limits still exist.
[Internet Explorer has a 2083-character limit on URLs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427). I think Firefox can handle more, but that's barely relevant if you want your site to work with IE anyway.

Signatures in URLs are tricky. There are workarounds where you'd strip the signature to the bare minimum: no certificate, no signer's name. In this case, the recipient is expected to know where the signature came from, and with which public key to verify it. This is more or less the [SAML HTTP Redirect binding does (around line 594)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf). If you can't use such tricks, you may just have to use POST.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 255-character limit in HTTP (the protocol). There maybe a limit in certain software components, though.

Also note that RFC 2068 is really ancient, the latest and greatest on this can be found here: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-19.html#rfc.section.3.1.1.p.10:

"Various ad-hoc limitations on request-line length are found in practice. It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of up to 8000 octets."